# Inline if statament to determine i++ or i-- increment in for loop

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to understand why my conditional if statement is giving me a compile error.
Is this not correct?

```
for(int i=startAt; i>=_itemsList.Count; length < 0 ? i-- : i++;)
{

}
```

Comment: What exact error? What for do you have extra `;` in the end?

Comment: I added the ; just to see if it would work with it there - but it wasn't there originally

Comment: Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement (CS0201)

Comment: Probably because the the statement, `length < 0 ? i-- : i++` is not a call, increment, decrement, or new object expression?

Comment: My point is - how can I have a conditional iteration that will be ++ (forward) or -- (reverse) in C# depending on some condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) it should be one of what the error message says:

- assignment statement
- invocation of a method
- prefix or postfix increment expression, such as ++i or i++
- prefix or postfix decrement expression, such as --i or i--
- creation of an object by using new
- await expression

One of the weird compilable solutions would be:

```
i += length < 0 ? -1 : 1
```

Comment: This isn't a workaround.  I also read this documentation.  What I really need to know is how I can I have a conditional iteration that will be ++ (forward) or -- (reverse) in C# depending on some condition?

Comment: @user1060500: this **IS** workaround. My expression does exactly what you want and is syntactically correct

Comment: My apologies - I missed the last part of your response when I read it.

Comment: @user1060500: yep, and in comparison to another question - this expression is not tricky and can be interpreted manually without need of reading of C# standard. I don't even mention that `i = i--` doesn't modify the value at all

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is zerkms, but there is another solution that should work.

```
int dummy = 0;
for(int i=startAt; i>=_itemsList.Count; dummy++)
{
  // Do your thing
  length < 0 ? i-- : i++;
}
```